# what is the fastest way of loading images?

Tags: pytorch

I have about 200,000 high resolution images, and loading such high quality images every time is time consuming.
Preloading all images might occupy too much memory.
How about saving each images into .npz file format and loading .npz instead of .jpg?  Would it be boosting speed?

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to load all the image to memory at once. Considering also that we need to do data augmentation on the dataset during model training, it is impossible to load all images.

In PyTorch, you can use [`Dataset`](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset) to store your training and validation set. The `Dataset` class has a parameter `transforms`(e.g., Scale, RandomCrop, etc.), which is used to transform the training image on the fly during training. Several ready-made dataset are also provided by `torchvision` package, see [here](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/torchvision/datasets.html).

#### Basic methold

PyTorch's builtin [`Dataloader`](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) has a `num_worker`, which is used to control how many subprocess you use for loading the data. Since your dataset is not so huge, that would be enough for your need. About how to set the appropriate number of worker, see [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/guidelines-for-assigning-num-workers-to-dataloader/813).

#### More references

There are discussion on PyTorch forum on fast image loading, use [post1](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/fast-data-loader-for-imagenet/988/9) and [post2](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/whats-the-best-way-to-load-large-data/2977/4) as a start.

Comment: in Caffe I use *net.input.data[...] = im* and *net.forward()*. Is it possible to do something like this is pytorch, without the Dataset interface?

Comment: Yes, if `img` is a torch tensor, `model` is your network. You can just use `out = model(img)` to get the output of a model.

Comment: That's interesting, I needed to convert tensor to *Variable* type to use it as an input

Comment: In the latest version of PyTorch (version 0.4.0), Variable is deprecated. You do not need to use Variable to wrap a tensor.