# How to speed up the "ImageFolder" for ImageNet

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, pytorch, imagenet, torchvision

I am in an university, and all the file system are in a remote system, wherever I log in with my account, I could aways access my home directory. even though I log into the GPU servers through SSH command. This is the condition where I employ the GPU servers to read data.

Currently, I use the PyTorch to train ResNet from scratch on ImageNet, my codes only use all the GPUs in the same computer, I found that the "torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder" will take almost two hours.

Would you please provide some experiences in how to speed up "torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder"? Thanks very much.

Comment: Did you try using more `num_workers`? Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47644367/what-is-the-fastest-way-of-loading-images. Also, you may try HDF5 file as suggested on https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-speed-up-the-data-loader/13740

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your reply. My problem is occured with the ImageFolder, while the num_worker is set to the next sentence. I try to move the files to the local machine that is a SSD, I found the data loading only need several seconds. So I think the problem is caused by the remote file system.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution for fast loading on remote file system (NAS) ?

Comment: Finally, I copy the data to the disk of the GPU server.

Answer (score 1):

**Why it takes so long?**
Setting up an [`ImageFolder`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/datasets.html#imagefolder) can take a long time, especially when the images are stored on a slow remote disk. The reason for this latency is that the `__init__` function for the dataset goes over all files in the image folders and check whether this file is an image file. For ImageNet that can take quite a while as there are over 1 million files to check.

**What can you do?**
- As [Kevin Sun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54207204/how-to-speed-up-the-imagefolder-for-imagenet#comment96783876_54207204) already pointed out, copying the dataset to a local (and possibly much faster) storage can significantly speed up things.
- Alternatively, you can create a modified dataset class that does not read all the files, but relies on a *cached* list of files - a cached list that you prepare *only once* in advance and to be used for all runs.

Comment: Can you provide details on how to create such a cached list?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the folder structure doesn't change you can cache the structure (not the data which is too large) using the following:

```py
import json
from functools import wraps
from torchvision.datasets import ImageNet

def file_cache(filename):
    """Decorator to cache the output of a function to disk."""
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated(self, directory, *args, **kwargs):
            filepath = Path(directory) / filename
            if filepath.is_file():
                out = json.loads(filepath.read_text())
            else:
                out = f(self, directory, *args, **kwargs)
                filepath.write_text(json.dumps(out))
            return out
        return decorated
    return decorator

class CachedImageNet(ImageNet):
    @file_cache(filename="cached_classes.json")
    def find_classes(self, directory, *args, **kwargs):
        classes = super().find_classes(directory, *args, **kwargs)
        return classes

    @file_cache(filename="cached_structure.json")
    def make_dataset(self, directory, *args, **kwargs):
        dataset = super().make_dataset(directory, *args, **kwargs)
        return dataset
```